# Can I delete my Rock Band 2 content?

Tags: rock-band-3, rock-band-2

We bought Rock Band 3 and want to do the song transfer which will take 1.9 gigs.  Can I delete the main Rock Band 2 content to free space?

Comment: What console is this for? The Wii has inherantly different storage (i.e., no hard drive) than the ps3 or 360.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about your Rock Band 2 *save file* that contains your bands and your preferences, deleting them won't help because they're so tiny to begin with.

If you mean your Rock Band *songs*, it might help depending on how many you have. You will always be able to download them again later on without paying again, but it might be a pain as you have to do them all individually.